# How can a http.createServer receive data from needle.post using fs.createReadStream

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to send an image from a nodejs server to another nodejs server.

I understand there are a lot of solutions, but I hoping to find out how to do it in the following way:

**Server A (Sender)**

Option 1

```
needle.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000', fs.createReadStream('test.png'), function(err, resp, body) {               
});
```

Option 2

```
var reader = fs.createReadStream('test.png');
reader.pipe(request.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000'));
```

**Server B (Receiver)**

```
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  if (req.method === 'PUT' || req.method === 'POST') {
     req.on('data', function(chunked) {
        // I got nothing here
     });
     res.on('data', function(chunked) {
        // I got nothing here
     });
  }
}).listen(8000, function() {
  console.log('Listening for requests');
});
```

The problem is that if I read the file data that is sent over using fs.createReadStream, I am not able to receive any data from Server B.

[Edit] Also need to know how to handle the above using Express

Comment: With `console.log(chunked);` in `req.on('data'`, and option 1 of Server A, it works well in my local test...

Comment: my bad, I have just realised my test.png is blank

Comment: Thanks, if handling it using Express, the behaviour on receiving end is different as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to create the fs.createWriteStream() and assign to req.pipe().

```
...
var saveTo = './test.png',
    ws = fs.createWriteStream(saveTo);

ws.on('close', function () {
    cb();
});
req.pipe(ws);
...
```

Comment: Thanks, when using Express, I can receive using the above statements

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by zangw in comments, the script actually works. My bad that my test.png is blank

Comment: Ignore this answer, made another mistake